# WordPress not using my javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create ajax form submitting and validation with jQuery, but wordpress refuses to execute my code.

I've this snippet, working on http://jsfiddle.net

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Test");
    $('.sendbutton').click(function(){
        var nimi = $('input[name=nimi]').val();
        var viesti = $('textarea[name=viesti]').val();
        $('.control-group').removeClass("error");

        if(nimi == ""){
        $('.control-group#nimi').addClass("error");
        return false;    
        }
        if(viesti == ""){
        $('.control-group#viesti').addClass("error");
        return false;    
        }
        var message = $('#contact').serialize();
        alert(message);return false;
        $.ajax({
        data : message,
        error : function(){alert('Viestiäsi ei lähetetty. Yritä uudelleen?');},
        success : function(){alert('Onnistui');}




        });
        return false;
    });
});​
```

But it won't work on  wordpress, or on my theme. I'm using Roots theme (Twitter Bootstrap) and I've tried placing the code in plugins.js as jQuery UI is working and I placed it there, but no. Including the script from a different file

Comment: try to add this script in your `wp-content/themes/Roots theme/header.php`.

Comment: I think that I said that it didn't work to include the script in head.

Comment: Actually you didn't, as evidenced by the above.

Comment: i suggest you use chrome, then `view element` see whether there has js error in it?

Comment: Well, it won't work if I include it on the head.

Comment: It has no errors, it works fine if I don't use wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From codex :

> The jQuery library included with WordPress loads in "[no conflict](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)"
>   mode. This is to prevent compatibility problems with other javascript
>   libraries that WordPress can load.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

You should use :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about that because I only use jQuery.